# Code after ForEach runs before loop is finished

Tags: node.js, foreach

I am attempting to get a list of roles in a discord server, find the role owner, its members, and its rep however the INSERT query is happening before the ForEach is even finished... I looked around and all the solutions are old or turn my code from a few lines to 100+ lines...

````
con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return msg.reply({embed: {color: 16711686,description: "\\❌ | Failed to connect to database - Contact **TheeDeer**"}})
             .then(say => {
                msg.delete();
                say.delete(3000);
              });
        }
        msg.guild.roles.forEach(function(role) {
            if (role.name !== "@everyone") {
                if (role.id !== "509854902525231106" || role.id !== "509864772154687488" || role.id !== "509862522921287692" || role.id !== "526336817386225675" || role.id !== "509852743909900321" || role.id !== "526336702298456064" || role.id !== "509872838891536384" || role.id !== "509870184115339286" || role.id !== "511409235364413446" || role.id !== "509850967932665857" || role.id !== "527116001880309762" || role.id !== "509864108024397849" || role.id !== "511409106683297792" || role.id !== "526897893181882388" || role.id !== "509864540129853450" || role.id !== "509870488634523648" || role.id !== "509869899490000897" || role.id !== "511420878664237056" || role.id !== "509850657164099604" || role.id !== "526336636523380758" || role.id !== "510975537733173259" || role.id !== "509855069584490498" || role.id !== "517564552108441626" || role.id !== "509868843863244800" || role.id !== "509857751728652289" || role.id !== "510974779818377227") {
                    var ID = role.id;
                    var clanName = role.name;
                    var clanMembers = [];
                    var clanOwner = "";
                    var clanRep = [];
                    role.members.forEach( function(member, index) {
                         member.roles.forEach( function(memberRole, index) {
                            if (memberRole.id == "509869899490000897" || memberRole.id == "509881406810357792") {
                               clanOwner = member.id;
                            } else if (memberRole.id == "509870184115339286") {
                                clanRep.push(member.id);
                            } else {
                                clanMembers.push(member.id);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    clanRep = clanRep.toString();
                    clanMembers = clanMembers.toString();
                    if (!clanMembers || !clanOwner) { failedClans.push(clanName); return; }
                    clanList.push([ID,
                        clanName,
                        clanMembers,
                        clanOwner,
                        clanRep]
                    );
                    addedClans.push(clanName)
                }
            }
        });
        await console.log(clanList);
        var sql = "INSERT INTO clans (roleID,clanName,clanMembers,clanOwner,clanRep) VALUES ?";
        con.query(sql,[clanList], function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            return msg.reply({embed: {color: 16711686,description: "Added the following clans \n``` "+addedClans.toString()+" ```\n Failed to add the following ``` "+failedClans.toString()+" ```"}});
        });
    });
````

Comment: Is it good version of your code? You use "await" in no-async function and you are trying to await console.log....

Answer (score 0):

for resolution of this issue i suggest you to define your own custom async version of forEach loop.Rationale behind this is than you can await the execution of foreach loop and it will resolve your problem.

Step 1: Define your own async version of forEach.

```
const asyncForEach = async (array, callback) => {
 for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
 await callback(array[index]);
  }
};
```

Step 2: now you can use the "asyncForEach version in your code like below"

```
await asyncForEach(msg.guild.roles, yourcallbackfunction);
con.query(.....your insert query.....);
// now if you put your Sql insert query after the above awaited asyncForEach
// it will definitely execute only once your asyncForEach execution is 
// finished.
```

I have faced a similar situation and this async version of foreach works like a charm for me only diffrence is i was using elasticsearch.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Array.forEach is blocking, I suspect something else might be wrong there, i.e a logic flaw causing "clanList" to not be populated like you expect it to be.

**console.log()** an integer counter variable on every iteration of the main loop just to see that it does indeed execute before the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and my research thought me the following:

JavaScript `forEach` function executes code synchronously regardless of using it with or without the async and await keywords, which are meant to run code asynchronously.

**However, it will run with unexpected behaviors.**

**Solution:**

1. Use any of these for loop `for(…;…;…)` or `for ... of`
2. This solution works if the code in the for loop doesn't have to be sequential. Use `Array.map()` method to get an array of promises and execute all promises using `Promise.all`

```js
await Promise.all(
    msg.guild.roles.map(async (role) => {
      // execute your asynchronous functions
    })
);
```